Wifi and Bluetooth settings not showing
In the menu , I couldn't find wifi and Bluetooth options. I couldn't find it in settings too. I am new to ubuntu

Can you edit the question to include results from terminal for lspci -nnk|grep -iA3 net; lsusb
